# Closed orientable 4-manifold with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ and non-zero cup product $H^1\times H^1\to H^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for an example of a closed orientable 4-manifold $M$ with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$ and non-zero cup product $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\times H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^2(M;\Bbb Z_2)$.

A non-orientable example is $\Bbb RP^4$. An orientable example of dimension 3 is $\Bbb RP^3$.

I have asked at math stackexchange and the question was upvoted but no answers have been given.

Comment: Any closed manifold has non-zero cup product by Poincare duality.  So $S^1\times S^2$ satisfies your criteria.

Comment: Original math.SE post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325568/264

Comment: @BenWebster Sorry, I edited the question to clarify that I mean the cup-product $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\times H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^2(M;\Bbb Z_2)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a closed oriented simply-connected fourfold $N$ with a fixed point free involution $\sigma $, and put $M=N/\sigma $ (for a typical example, take for $M$ an Enriques surface). Then $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)=$ $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi _1(M),\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $x$ be the nonzero element of $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$; the square $x^2$ is the reduction (mod. 2) of $\beta x$, where  $\beta :H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)\rightarrow H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is the Bockstein homomorphism. If $x^2=0$, one  has $\beta x=2y$ for some class $y$ in $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$. But $\beta x\neq 0$ because $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$, hence $y$ is a 4-torsion class, which is impossible since $H^2(N,\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion free. Hence $x^2\neq 0$.

Comment: Why is M orientable?  If N is $S^4$ and $\sigma$ is the antipodal map, then $M = RP^4$ is an example of the construction you suggest and is not orientable, so there must be an additional condition to get M to be orientable.

Comment: I guess we're just looking for an example in which the involution in question is orientation-preserving.

Comment: Right. Sorry I didn't make it explicit.

Comment: Okay, so what's the simplest example where we can get the desired orientation-preserving involution?  Do all Enriques surfaces have such an involution?

Comment: This is the other way around: all Enriques surfaces have a double covering by a K3 surface, which has therefore an orientation-preserving (and fixed point free) involution.

Comment: @abx Could you please clarify why $y$ is 4-torsion? Also, in the last line you say $H^2(N,\mathbb Z)$, shouldn't it me $M$ instead of $N$? Sorry for not getting something very basic...

Comment: $y$ is 4-torsion because $2y=\beta x$ is 2-torsion. And I meant what I wrote : if $\pi :N\rightarrow M$ is the quotient map,  we have $\pi _*\pi ^*y=2y\neq 0$, hence $\pi ^*y$ is a nonzero torsion class in $H^2(N,\mathbb{Z})$.